# What is the proper way to calculate Left, right, top, bottom constraint according to different devices?

Tags: ios

Suppose i have a View controller in which there are two labels and they have ***112 vertical spacing*** between them for iphone 6 plus. If i want to keep this spacing for all types of devices as a aspect ratio, what will be the proper way?
Currently i am following one of two approaches.

**1. Stack View approach:**

In this approach i am taking

a. A stack view

b. Put that two labels into that Stack View

c. set spacing from storyboard.

d. multiply this spacing with the device aspect ratio. like this

```
#define SCREEN_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_IPHONE_6P (SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH/736.0)
```

**2. Normal Constraint Approach:**

Multiply vertical spacing(in my case 112) with the device aspect ratio just like ***approach 1.***

But what is actually the better way to handle this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your view to remain visually consistant across devices I usually convert my design specs into relative or percentage based sizes.

So for example, if you have a button at the bottom of the screen that is supposed (as per design) to have 24px of space from the bottom and side edges of the screen. I would look at the design and work out 24px as a percentage of the width of the screen (in the design). This would mean that the spacing/padding is consistent on all devices.

In regards to fonts, I would usually set the font size as per design but where possible I would allow it to reduce the size to fit using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumScaleFactor` like in UILabels.

Hope this helps

Comment: That is you are following step 2 as you mentioned percentage.

Comment: yes, there isn't really a better solution. a 24px spacing for example would look very different on a iPhone 5 compared to a iPhone 7+